# Using Google docs in a multi-tenant SaaS application

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-docs, saas

I am building a multitenant SaaS application for multipule companies to use.  One of the features of the application is that it will create a document based from database data.

I could use a library to create a document in MS-word format and this would be downloaded to the users PC or stored in a database.

However, I love Google Docs and ideally the output would be a google doc.

My struggle is know how I would do this?  Can I subscribe to google docs with my SaaS company and the my software creates the google doc in it's own account and this doc is then shared with the client?  (i.e. all the docs are in my SaaS companies google drive.)  Or can I get my SaaS app to hook in with the clients Google account and the document is created in their google account/drive?  But then they would need a Google account and what happens if they dont have one?

I am looking for the best way to do this

Comment: I'm looking to do the same thing. Either with MS or Google Docs. Did you find a nice solution?